# How to use st_touches to get all nearby states

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table with all US states geometrical data:

```
USstate
-------

state   | The_geom (here filling in random value)

AL      | 00012312 
NM      | 000234234
NJ      | 0000234534
NY      | 00005465
VA      | 0000023434456
```

I want to compute number of neighboring states for each state. I know st_touches() has to be used but I am not able to form the exact query. I think it should be something similar to below:

```
select count(*) as neighbors, st_touches(s.the_geom, r.the_geom) 
from USstates as s, USstates as r 
GROUP BY USsates.state;
```

I am not sure if this is right. Please let me know how to correct this.

Comment: Did you try anything before posting your latest homework question?

Comment: Not sure why you removed the rest of your question, where you appear to show an attempted solution. It might have been ok then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
select s.state, count (r.state) as neighbors
  from USstates as s, USstates as r
 where st_touches (s.the_geom, r.the_geom)
   and s.state != r.state
group by s.state
```

Comment: @Rdvsm: Did it work without any changes? I didn't have any way of testing it.

Comment: thanks Martin, I dont have the table to test. I was trying to get an idea how I can use st_touches to find the negihbours. Hope it works. I am trying to get states data online. If I find it I will try it and let you know.Thanks

Comment: @martinf. Be aware that this is homework. Your answer is perfect, but there has been a flood of questions the last few days, here and on SO, asking questions like this, with 0 effort being shown, often by different users asking identical questions within minutes of each other.

Comment: @JohnBarça: This one *did* appear to have shown effort, but it's been edited away.

Comment: @martinf, sorry I didn't realize. I don't have enough rep to see edits yet on here.